# Unable to access class attributes using object pointers

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm new to c++. My problem is that I am able to call Init() from inside my class, but I am not able to call it from main using a pointer. After some troubleshooting, it seems that the problem is that when I call Init() from main, c++ can't see the parameters that I pass in (_ip, _user, ... ). Below, I have one example that works, and the second that doesn't. Would anyone be able to explain to me why the second example doesn't work?

Thanks a bunch,

This works (displays res: 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

/*
Include directly the different
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"
#include "cppconn/prepared_statement.h"

using namespace std;

class MySQLdb {

    public:
        MySQLdb(string ip, string user, string passwd, string schema);      //Create Connection
        ~MySQLdb();

        bool Init();                                                        //Initialize Connection

    private:        
        const char* _ip;                                                    //MySQL credentials
        const char* _user;
        const char* _passwd;
        const char* _schema;
        int x = 0;

        sql::Driver *_driver;                                               //MySQL attributes
        sql::Connection *_con;
        sql::Statement *_stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *_res;
        sql::PreparedStatement *_pstmt;
};

MySQLdb::MySQLdb(string ip, string user, string passwd, string schema)
{
    string ip_buffer = "tcp://" + ip;
    _ip = ip_buffer.c_str();
    _user = user.c_str();
    _passwd = passwd.c_str();
    _schema = schema.c_str();

    cout << "res: " << Init();
}
MySQLdb::~MySQLdb()
{
    delete _res;
    delete _stmt;
    delete _con;
}

bool MySQLdb::Init()
{
    // Create a connection
    _driver = get_driver_instance();
    _con = _driver->connect(_ip, _user, _passwd);
    _con->setSchema(_schema);

    if (!_con->isClosed())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    try{
        MySQLdb* db = new MySQLdb(IP_ADDRESS, USER, PASSWD, DB);

        delete db;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {

        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This does not work (error: unable to connect to host because it cannot read any of the variables passed into the class constructor):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

/*
Include directly the different
headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
(and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"
#include "cppconn/prepared_statement.h"

using namespace std;

class MySQLdb {

    public:
        MySQLdb(string ip, string user, string passwd, string schema);      //Create Connection
        ~MySQLdb();

        bool Init();                                                        //Initialize Connection

    private:        
        const char* _ip;                                                    //MySQL credentials
        const char* _user;
        const char* _passwd;
        const char* _schema;
        int x = 0;

        sql::Driver *_driver;                                               //MySQL attributes
        sql::Connection *_con;
        sql::Statement *_stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *_res;
        sql::PreparedStatement *_pstmt;
};

MySQLdb::MySQLdb(string ip, string user, string passwd, string schema)
{
    string ip_buffer = "tcp://" + ip;
    _ip = ip_buffer.c_str();
    _user = user.c_str();
    _passwd = passwd.c_str();
    _schema = schema.c_str();
}
MySQLdb::~MySQLdb()
{
    delete _res;
    delete _stmt;
    delete _con;
}

bool MySQLdb::Init()
{
    // Create a connection
    _driver = get_driver_instance();
    _con = _driver->connect(_ip, _user, _passwd);
    _con->setSchema(_schema);

    if (!_con->isClosed())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    try{
        MySQLdb* db = new MySQLdb(IP_ADDRESS, USER, PASSWD, DB);

        db->Init();

        delete db;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {

        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior. The lifetime of the strings passed to the constructor end when it finished. The pointer values you get from those strings become invalid once the strings are destroyed

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the other answer, you need to allocate and copy the memory for the new string, something like:

```
string ip_buffer = "tcp://" + ip;
_ip = new char [ip_buffer.length() + 1];
std::strcpy (_ip, ip_buffer.c_str());
```

I'm not sure as it has been a long time since I coded in C++ but I think that you also need to remove the `const` attribut from the declaration of `_ip`.